# If $f$ is an entire function and $f = f'$ then the is a constant $K$ such that $f(z) = Ke^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove that if $f$ is an entire function (holomorphic in all the complex space) and $f = f'$ then there is a complex constant $K$ such that $f(z)  = Ke^z$.

Moreover, I need to show that $e^z = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Well I am not so sure what to do here. I see that $f-f' = $ constant, but I don't think it helps. I can clearly show that if $f(z) = Ke^z$ it satisfies the conditions, but I am not sure how to prove that $f$ is necessarily such a function.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: An entire function $f$ can be written as a serie on the all $\mathbb{C}$ : $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n$. You can derive this expression and use the identity $f=f^\prime$ to find the coefficients.

Comment: Show that $g(z)=f(z)e^{-z}$ satisfies $g'=0$